# MATLAB: Determine the exact solution using dsolve

Tags: matlab

I'm working on a project where I implemented Runge Kutta 2nd, 3rd and 4th order. The last requirement in the project says: "For the study of performance you can use distinct differential equations, use dsolve to determine the exact solution.".
If I have something like dy/dx=-2*y+x+4
How am I supposed to solve it using dsolve and calculate the value of y in several values of x? I calculated with RK its values in 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. I want to find the difference between the result of RK and the exact solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the symbolic math toolbox, so I can't test this, but it looks like

```
S = dsolve('Dy = -2*y+x+4', 'x');
```

will give you an array of solutions in S. http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/symbolic/dsolve.html

Comment: this is what I get "S = x/2 + C5/(4*exp(2*x)) + 7/4". What is C5?